# custom cell and custom height for each

Tags: swift, коллекции, uicollectionview

Я вывел 4 кастомных ячейки через функцию `switch`
теперь мне нужно для каждой из вывести либо динамическое значение высоты, либо фиксированное. Мне подходит любой из вариантов, так как их высота всегда будет статична.

я подписался под протокол `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`
и нашел как изменить высоту всех ячеек

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let size = CGSize(width: 357, height: 600)
        return size
```

чтоб переопределить высоту отдельных ячеек я использую функцию

```
cell.frame = CGRect(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
```

но она не работает, так как "Expression type '@lvalue CGRect' is ambiguous without more context"

как мне поступить в таком случае? какую функцию использовать?

полный код ниже

```
// main protocols UICollectionView
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    // width and height for cell in collectionView
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let size = CGSize(width: 357, height: 600)
        return size
    }


    //margins for cell in collectionView
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
        collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 40.0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


            var cell: UICollectionViewCell!

            switch indexPath.row {
            case 1:
                cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "secondCell", for: indexPath)
                    as? secondCollectionViewCell
                cell.frame = CGRect(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, width: 100.0, height: 100.0)

            case 2:
                cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "thirdCell", for: indexPath)
                    as? thirdCollectionViewCell

            case 3:
                cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "fourthCell", for: indexPath)
                    as? fourthCollectionViewCell

            default:
                cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath)
                    as? imageModelCollectionViewCell
            }
            return cell
        }
    }
```

Еще раз уточняю
есть три case + default значение. 
Все кейсы отображаются ячейки одновременно, последовательно

Для каждой ячейки мне нужно вывести кастомную высоту, не затрагивая высоту других.

Например

```
case 1 - высота 100;
case 2 - высота 500;
case 3 - высота 70;
default - высота 80;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не должны использовать

```
cell.frame = CGRect(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
```

Вместо этого вам надо указать конкретный размер возвращаемой функцией sizeForItemAt, например:

```
extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            return CGSize(width: 100, height: 200)
        case 1:
            return CGSize(width: 100, height: 300)
        case 2:
            return CGSize(width: 100, height: 400)
        default:
            return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        }
    }
}
```

Не забудьте убедиться, что вы указали делегат:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: при попытке добавить для каждого кейса 
return CGSize(width: 100, height: 200)
Выводит ошибку
Cannot convert return expression of type 'CGSize' to return type 'UICollectionViewCell'

Comment: Вы вставили код не в функцию sizeForItemAt, а в cellForItemAt. Это разные функции.

Comment: Иван, спасибо кажется я понял в чем допустил ошибку 

Не могли бы вы показать на примере моего кода, как правило это реализовать?

Спасибо

Comment: У вас все правильно. Уберите строку cell.frame = CGRect(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, width: 100.0, height: 100.0) и добавьте мой код.

Comment: Иван, можете взгялнуть на мой новый код под сноской //update? я обновил его в посте

Comment: У вас сейчас 2 функции вложены друг в друга.

Comment: Спасибо. Это был отличный совет, все работает.
Я немного подправил Ваш комментарий, чтоб предостеречь людей в будущем от ошибки